# Serializing to XML and compressing the result - how to add a XML filetype?

Tags: c#, xml, file-io

I am using the following method to serialize objects:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes a file to a compressed XML file. If an error occurs, the exception is NOT caught.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The Type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="obj">The object.</param>
    /// <param name="fileName">Name of the file.</param>
    public static void SerializeToXML<T>(T obj, string fileName)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (var compressor = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(compressor, obj);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thats works without a hitch, but there is a minor problem: The method creates a .zip file which contains the compressed xml which has no file Extension at all. How can I modify this method, so that the correct file extension is added to the compressed file?

Example:
Suppose I have the following code:

```
public class test
{
   public string test {get; set;}
}

public void save()
{
  var newTest = new test();
  newTest.test = "bla";
  SerializeToXML(newTest, c:\test.zip")
}
```

Comment: GZipStream only creates a compressed stream. It doesn't create a full `zip` file, and you can't use it to create a file/directory structure inside that `zip` file. Try SharpZipLib if you need that - http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/

Comment: ah, so no chance to add a file extension before the stream is handed to GZipStream?

Comment: I'm affraid not. In fact, I'm quite surprised you can even open the zip file at all, since it's not a fully formed zip. That says nice things about your unzipper :)

Comment: you can try to rename file ''test.zip' to 'test.xml.zip' than after decompression zip extension will be removed and you will have only xml :)

Comment: @Luaan I use the Gzipstream to decompress it, but 7zip can handle the result just fine - so I never caught the fact that this is malformed zip.

Comment: The notation Jevgenij is suggesting is the standard for gzips on *nix systems, so you might as well go with that. That's probably also how 7zip is reading it - it ignores your (~wrong) `zip` extension, and reads it as if it had `gz` extension. And `gz` files don't have all those pesky file tables etc.

Comment: @JevgenijNekrasov Could you post this as anweser?

Comment: @Luaan could you post your comments as answer?

Comment: Great answers by @Luaan and @JevgenijNekrasov. Btw in the interests of clarity, or minimising surprise, I suggest you rename `SerializeToXML` to `SerializeAndCompress`: the method does more than one thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to rename file `'test.zip'` to `'test.xml.zip'` then after decompression zip extension will be removed and you will have only xml.

Answer (score 2):

GZipStream only creates a compressed stream. It doesn't create a full zip file, and you can't use it to create a file/directory structure inside that zip file.

Try SharpZipLib if you need that - icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib

If you don't, just continue using GZipStream, but note that the resulting file is a `gzip` file, not `zip`. The somewhat standardised notation for gzips is basically to include the filename of the uncompressed file in the filename of the compressed file (what Jevgenij said), eg. `test.xml.gz`. This should yield the "correct" file name when you unzip the file using 7zip, gunzip or other tools that handle this "properly".